# Printing numbers that are not multiples of 7 and 2

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java and I've found myself in a bit of a conundrum. My logic for solving the question is right but my logical operators aren't working the way I expected them to. Here's the program I've written:

```
public class idgaf {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=25;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if((i%7!=0)||(i%2!=0)){
            System.out.print(i+" ");

        }
    }
}
```

Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25

I expected the OR operator to do its thing and not show any multiples of 7 and 2 but yet, the only number removed is 14, which is a multiple of both 7 and 2.
I tried the same code with AND operator and gave me the right output.

Output with AND operator: 1 3 5 9 11 13 15 17 19 23 25

It seems as if the AND operator is working the I expected the OR operator to work and vice versa. Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: If what you want is to print numbers that aren't multiples of 7 AND 2 then the if statement should be   if((i%7!=0) && (i%2!=0))

Comment: You *don't* want to print if `i % 7` is zero OR `i % 2` is zero. To negate that condition you can use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: But doesn't the && operator check if both conditions are met by each number and then print them?

Comment: 14 is the only number below 25 which is "Not a multiple or 7 OR not a multiple of 2".

Comment: Using the or operator should be: if( !(i%7==0 || i%2==0) )

Comment: And when making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please *copy-paste* it into the question. Don't try to rewrite it because that can add unrelated errors by mistake (or sometimes even *fix* the problem by mistake). For example you write `i%2!=10` when you most likely mean `i%2!=0`.

Comment: Finally, do some research about [the Fizz Buzz test](http://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest), which your program is a variant of.

Answer (score 2):

Check your condition. It should be:

```
    if((i%7 != 0) && (i%2 != 0)){ .....
```

`i%7!=0` //cannot  divide by 7

`i%2!=0` // cannot divide by 2

join them with AND and you got the right result

Answer (score 0):

The correct version would be

```
public class idgaf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 25;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            // here are two adjustments, && instead of || and % 2 != 0 (not 10)
            if ((i % 7 != 0) && (i % 2 != 0)) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something new?

Something like this using java 8, which will just return the top `k` integers that meet your requirements:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(getTopK(10));
}

private static List<Integer> getTopK(int k) {
    return IntStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .filter(i -> i % 7 != 0 && i % 2 != 0)
            .limit(k).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And the output if `k = 10` will be:

```
[1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 23]
```

Comment: Maybe you can speed up that a bit by replacing ``i % 7 != 0 && i % 2 != 0`` by ``i % 14 != 0``, but maybe the JIT compiler will do this already for you ...

Answer (score 0):

in python program:

```
for n in range(0, 101, 7):
      print(n)
```

*prints the multiples of 7 between 0 and 100. Print one multiple per line and avoid printing any numbers that aren't multiples of 7. Remember that 0 is also a multiple of 7*